# IE8 CSS Text Spacing Issue Text-Justify

Tags: html, css, fancybox

I'm running into a CSS text justify issue in ie8 and need to create a ie8 specific rule to address the issue, but I'm not too familiar with the process.

The page & text is supposed to look like so: **[Link to Page](http://tinyurl.com/d3va35m)** (Use modern browser like Chrome / Safari / Firefox).

Img attached showing ie8 spacing.[image: ie8 text spacing issue]

How can I fix this? Your help is much appreciated as always!

**CSS**

```
/*Fancybox Gallery Divs*/


#thumbs {   
    width: 960px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

#thumbs a {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}

/*Descriptions*/


#desc-wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

.description {
    float:left;
    width: 320px; // Increase/decrease width for margin between images
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--/ Photo Thumbs Row 1-->

<div id="thumbs">

<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/roscoes-run.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/roscoes-run(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/roscoes-run-2.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/roscoes-run-2(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/chicken-waffles.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/chicken-waffles(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>

<span class="stretch"></span>


</div>

<!--/ Description-->

<div id="desc-wrapper">
<div class="description">Roscoe's Run 2012</div>
<div class="description">Roscoe's Run 2012</div>
<div class="description">Roscoe's Run 2012</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>




<!--/ Photo Thumbs Row 2-->

<div id="thumbs">

<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/mens-retreat-2012.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/mens-retreat-2012(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/winter-retreat-2012.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/winter-retreat-2012(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>
<a id="single_image" href="/bp/images/new-years-eve-2012.jpg"><img src="/bp/images/new-years-eve-2012(thumb).jpg" alt=""/></a>


<span class="stretch"></span>

</div>


<!--/ Description-->

<div id="desc-wrapper">
<div class="description">Men's Retreat 2012</div>
<div class="description">Winter Retreat 2012</div>
<div class="description">New Year's Eve 2012</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't have to add a new `DOCTYPE` and a `<head>` section every time you add a new css stylesheet ... IE will jump for sure.

Comment: Fix your HTML, it contains [38 errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbondofperfection.com%2Fmedia.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I could really use some help with this weird ie8 issue, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `text-justify: inter-word` to the .description style.